# require() of ES Module when using @nuxtjs/composition-api

Tags: nuxt.js, require, es6-modules, vue-composition-api, storyblok

I have the following error in my nuxt-2 + storyblok project, when I switched from `@vue/composition-api` to `@nuxtjs/composition-api`:

`require() of ES Module /Users/my-user/Sites/my-project/node_modules/@nuxtjs/composition-api/dist/runtime/index.mjs not supported. Instead change the require of /Users/my-user/Sites/my-project/node_modules/@nuxtjs/composition-api/dist/runtime/index.mjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.`

my console log also throws: `Uncaught InternalError: too much recursion`

I already use `"type":"module"` in my package.json. -> It makes no difference whether I remove it or not.

Some version info from my package.json:

- "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
- "@nuxtjs/composition-api": "^0.33.1",
- "@storyblok/nuxt-2": "^1.1.0",
- "core-js": "^3.19.3",

I included the composition-api like this

```
modules: [
  '@nuxtjs/composition-api/module',
  ...
],
```

On Stackoverflow there are others who have this issue with `node-fetch`, but I don't have this dependency installed.

I could update from `@nuxtjs/composition-api` to [Nuxt Bridge](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/bridge/overview), but it's a lot of changes and I am not sure it helps, or my code even works with Bridge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrading to @nuxtjs/composition-api version 0.29.3 solved the issue. [Version 0.30.0](https://github.com/nuxt-community/composition-api/releases/tag/0.30.0) starts to use mjs which seems to not be compatible with the current version of @storyblok/nuxt-2.

Answer (score 1):

Hi have you tried to move it to "buildModules" and remove the "/module" in the url?
It should be:

```
  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/composition-api',
    ...
  ],
```

Comment: I switched to buildModules but still the same. v0.33.1 needs /module. I'll try different versions now ...

Comment: Check that you dont have anything weird in your package.json, like a `"type": "module"`. It seems like your project is fairly old.